# Apache Camel quartz2 timer starting multiple exchanges

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have an application that creates routes to connect to a REST endpoint and process the responses for several vendors.  Each route is triggered with a quartz2 timer.  Recently when the timer fires it creates multiple exchanges instead of just one and I cannot determine what is causing it.

The method that creates the routes is here:

```
    public String generateRoute(String vendorId) {

        routeBuilders.add(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Building REST input route for vendor " + vendorId);
                String vendorCron = vendorProps.getProperty(vendorId + ".rest.cron");
                String vendorEndpoint =  vendorProps.getProperty(vendorId + ".rest.endpoint");
                String vendorAuth = vendorProps.getProperty(vendorId + ".rest.auth");
                int vendorTimer = Integer.valueOf(vendorId) * 10000;
                GsonDataFormat format = new GsonDataFormat(RestResponse.class);
                from("quartz2://timer" + vendorId + "?cron=" + vendorCron)
                        .routeId("Rte-vendor" + vendorId)
                        .streamCaching()
                        .log("Starting route " + vendorId)
                        .setHeader("Authorization",constant(vendorAuth))
                        .to("rest:get:" + vendorEndpoint)
                        .to("direct:processRestResponse")
                        .end();

            };
        });
        return "direct:myRoute." + vendorId;
```

and a sample 'vendorCron' string is

```
"*+5+*+*+*+?&trigger.timeZone=America/New_York".
```

When the quartz route fires I see this type of output in the log

```
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
15:39| INFO | CamelLogger.java 159 | Starting route 4
```

When I should ( and used to) only see one of these.

Any ideas what would cause this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `vendorCron`

- If Cron trigger is every 5secs then you see this log in every 5 secs..
- If Cron trigger is every 5mins/hours you see these login in 5 mins/hours.

Comment: I did not realize the vendorCron string posted incorrectly - the astericks are missing  - it is actually "*+5+*+*+*+?"  I have edited the original post to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I was staring so hard I missed the obvious.  I need a 0 in the seconds place of the cron expression.

Thank you for the time.